# SQL Server : setting language while creating view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I need to have months in my language in this view. I try this:

```
CREATE VIEW countTask
AS
    SET LANGUAGE Polish

    SELECT COUNT(*), DATENAME(Month, startdate), YEAR(startdate)
    FROM TBL_TASKS
    GROUP BY YEAR(startdate), DATENAME(Month, startdate)
```

but it's not correct. Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass a culture to `DATENAME` and you can't `SET LANGUAGE` in a view (as already mentioned by @Mike) but if you're on SQL Server 2012 or above you can use `FORMAT` instead. Something like

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM', 'pl-PL')

-----------
czerwiec

(1 row(s) affected)
```

- `MMMM` is full month name
- `MMM`  is abbreviated form
- `MM`   is month number
- (and `M` is month and day)

`FORMAT` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx

Date format strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can't put the `set Language` inside the view. The view is universal. if you want to see the output from the view in Polish, Set Language Polish before you select from it:

```
SET LANGUAGE Polish
SELECT * FROM countTask
```